# remove useless dot files in Linux

Tags: configuration, dot-files

Hi :D I had alot of packages that are removed now( im using manjaro so i deleted them with pamac ), but their dot files or their config folder in `~/.config` folder still remains, its not a big deal since they're hidden( how ever if you use something like ls -a, its a HUGE mess :D ) , but i was wondering if there's a way to check which dot files are not used anymore or don't have a related package( or basically which dot files are useless ) and remove them? something like [Geek Uninstaller](https://geekuninstaller.com) in windows which checks your system for any config or registry or cache file left by the removed application and gives you the option to remove them too.

Comment: try asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/